# Android Studio - Spinner cannot be clicked when there's a ScrollView

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, spinner

I've just lost 3 days trying to know why my Spinner cannot be clicked. I tried to remove the ScrollView below and it magically works. Now, I **must** use ScrollView below the spinner and I can't understand why doesn't work

This is the layout:

```
     <Toolbar
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#3399ff"
            android:minWidth="25dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25pt">
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:id="@+id/mpSpinner" />
        </Toolbar>
    <ScrollView
            android:minWidth="25dp"
            android:minHeight="25dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

           <other things below.../>

</ScrollView>
```

The activity **doesn't** affect its operation, but here's the code:

```
class MotoParabolico : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_moto_parabolico)

        supportActionBar!!.hide()

        val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.mpSpinner)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dropdown_MP, R.layout.custom_spinner)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
}
```

Comment: First, a suggestion: it is not recommended to create an Android UI that has more elements than can fit the screen and you have to scroll. Consider using several activities/fragments instead. Now on your problem, the click event is consumed by the ScrollView, so you have to override the onClick method of the ScrollView and return false so the click is propagated to its children views.

Comment: It's still periodically necessary to have scroll hough, for an instance for lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it, the issue is that the ScrollView is overlapping your toolbar. You have to add some margin between the two views. Try that.

```
 <Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#3399ff"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minWidth="25dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/mpSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />
    </Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:minWidth="25dp">

       //Text view with large text scrollable
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
```